# Repeat a while loop

Tags: python

```
years = int(input("How many years?: "))

i= 0

temperaturer = {}

monthnumber = 1


nummer = 1

while i <= years:
print("Which is " + str(nummer) + ":a year?: ")
for i in range(0,13):
        temp = input("Month " + str(monthnumber) + ": ")
        monthnumber += 1
        if monthnumber == 13:
            break

 temperaturer.append(temp)
```

Is there a simple way to make this repeat itself as many times as asked in "How many years at the top?"

Answer (score 0):

```
years = int(input("How many years?: "))

numeral  = {1 : 'first', 2: 'second'} # and so on
data = {}

for year in range(1, years + 1):
    cur_year = input("Which is the " + numeral[year] + " year?: ")
    data[cur_year] = {}
    for month in range(1, 13):
            d = input("Month " + str(month) + ": ")
            data[cur_year][month] = d


print data

{2012: {1: 22,
        2: 1,
        3: 42,
        4: 22,
        5: 3,
        6: 22,
        7: 11,
        8: 23,
        9: 42,
        10: 1,
        11: 223,
        12: 23},
 2018: {1: 23,
        2: 2,
        3: 4,
        4: 1,
        5: 52,
        6: 235,
        7: 2,
        8: 52,
        9: 25,
        10: 25,
        11: 25,
        12: 25}
```

Comment: "which is the 1 year"?

Comment: @enigma mapping added

Comment: tbh, I'd probably have gone with "which is year 1?" for simplicity's sake, but it really doesn't matter

Comment: enigma, I actually went ahead and did that :) now the only issue is how do I make the whole thing repeat? It asks me for the 12 months, now I only want it to do it over and over again for as many times as the user said in the input as well as change to 2nd year 3rd year etc. And user3990145 what you wrote is probably fantastic but for a beginner like me, hard to read haha

Comment: @J.Se So there are really basic things. I've just added a store (dict) for your data.
You need to check basics things about loops, and python collections as lists and dicts.